# How to incoperate dropdown and search in ember

Tags: ember.js

I want to implement a filter for displaying data by using a dropdown and a search. The functionality should be like this,if i select for a particular value in dropdown it should filter the result by its criteria and if select "all" from dropdown itshould display all result. Another functionality is the search filter, filter by any criteria by search term. I want to know how to incoperate these actions and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ember-power-select, it handles what you want quite nicely